# How to reenable items in toolbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, ide

Im using VS 2015. Yesterday all my items in my toolbox went disabled and no matter what I try I cannot re-enable them. Anyone have similar issue?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to see what your solutions target framework is...could be that simple.. Right click your project in solution explorer, select "properties" at the bottom and check the target framework making sure its set to the appropriate framework..  for that toolbox item..

some items are sometimes hidden because of the framework you are targeting..